# Deserialize Json with array and list in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, json-deserialization

I have a problem to deserialize this json :

```
{"heading":["Date","item","Time"],
"Data":{"CAN":[["2023-09-04T17:48:05","B00412-E5015186",4]
, ["2023-09-04T17:47:03","B00412-E5015186",7],
,["2023-09-04T06:34:51","B00412-E5015186",5]]}}
```

i use

```
 Dim myObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyObject_Dati)(_json)
```

And I try with this object

```
 Public Class MyObject_Dati
    Public Property head_ As String()
    Public Property data As List(Of MyItem)
    Public Class MyItem_dati_doc
        Public Property DataOra As String()
    End Class
End class
```

The error is :
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object ....because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly

PAth Dati.CAN line 1

I think there is something wrong in definition of my object.
Thank you

Comment: of course there is a single comma in : "B00412-E5015186",7],,["2023-09-04T06:34:51

Comment: Make MyItem an array instead of a list: ```Public Property data As MyItem()```

Comment: Sorry but i try to use `code` Public Property datia As List(Of Myitem())  and also `code` Public Property datia As Myitem()  . Which is correct ? Another question : in myitem i must have 3 different proprieties because i have 3 fields or just one because it is an array ?

Comment: @tval It should be able to put a json array into a `List(Of T)` just fine.

Comment: `Data` is a single object in the json, not an array, but you have it as a `List` in your class definition.  Its contents are an array of arrays, not a single-dimensional array.  Have you tried using the Visual Studio capability to paste json as a class definition?

Comment: No , I use it infrequently json. how can i pass it as class ?

Comment: i solved it with `code`   Public Class Rootobject
        Public Property header As String()
        Public Property Data As Data
    End Class

    Public Class Data
        Public Property CAN()() As Object
    End Class